# TortoiseHg update fails with "Access is denied", how to work around that?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I've pulled in some changes to read-only files from a remote repository and I'm trying to update my working area, but I get `[Errno 13] ... Access is denied` errors when TortoiseHg tries to update the read-only files.

I'm wondering if there's a command, option, or setting that will solve this problem in the TortoiseHg GUI. I can't seem to updated read-only files from the command line, either, so I'm also interested command-line solutions as well.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, `attrib -r * /s` from the repository root will remove all read-only attributes from files.

Comment: Understood, but this doesn't solve my problem. The files need to stay read-only.

Comment: That makes it difficult to update the files :)  You may need some kind of hook/extension that tests for, removes, updates, then replaces the read only flag then, but I don't know of one.

Answer (score 1):

reconsider the requirement that they need to be readonly.  maybe a piece of the deployment script that makes them readonly on deploy instead of having them readonly in your working directory would be a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes read about the [makewritable extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MakewritableExtension), perhaps this may help you in any way ... unless it's still in alpha state?