# Jenkins job fails - access is denied - but why?

Tags: jenkins

I have this, bizarre situation. Jenkins is running without security enabled, behind my corporate firewall. Jenkins is signed in and running under a service account. The 'Pricing framework Tests' job runs through. Automated testing. Love it;

[image: confusion]

The job pricing tests checks out the repo at a location ...

Lets call it

```
\\aCorp\myDev\GraphModel
```

Which would appear to offer reasonable proof that the account has access to that location, it's workspace etc. The job that fails gives me this console message

```
abort: \\aCorp\myDev\SPOTProduction\.hg\requires: Access is denied
ERROR: Failed to clone
```

So it's pointing to the same place, and the permissions extend to subfolders. After 30 miuntes on the phone with infrastructure, we're stumped. They are convinced that access is not denied. Can anyone offer a suggestion on a debugging mechanism or possible cause?

Comment: Try to checkout locally on machine itself. What happens? Is an ssh key needed for the serviceaccount?

Comment: Thanks. I managed start a console on a local computer with the service account. Then I ran the mercurial commands again. The first path works, the second path didn't. In my mind this is a reasonable proof that something funky with the permissioning is happening. I cannot for the life of me imagine what, given the conditions above, but at least we know ...

Comment: There is no access configured on the mercurial side (I am totally unfamiliar with mercurial) that prevents the second checkout?

Comment: I do come across several access denied w/ mercurial [ie this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481754/tortoisehg-update-fails-with-access-is-denied-how-to-work-around-that) in combination with windows. Might be worth a shot